# vim - commandT open file but keep files list open

Tags: vim

Pretty much explained in the title, I want to search for a term with command t and open more than one file at a time, so I would like to find a way to keep the search window open after opening a new file.

A function that would fuzzy search and open all files in new split windows would be ideal.

Thanks for your time

---- EDIT ----

I suppose I could make my question more clear, so here it is.

I am looking for a way to:
1) Find files containing a pattern
2) Select the ones I actually need to edit
3) Open them in split windows

I do not mind if I do it from withing vim or from the terminal.

For example, if I could open a CommandT file search window, and then map control+enter to open the selected file AND keep the list of search results open, I would have the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

To open multiple files at a time using `vi/vim` editor, use the following syntax:

```
$ vi file1.txt file2.txt file(N)
```

To list open files, use the command:

```
:ls
```

Eg:

```
:ls
  1 %a   "file1.txt"                    linha 1
  2      "file2.txt"                    linha 0
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

To switch to `next` file, use the command: `:n` or `:bn`. And to switch previous to file ,use the command: `:p` or `:bp`.

You can also switch between all open files, using the following syntax:

```
:b file
```

*Note: :b choses the last visited file, so you can use it to switch quickly between two files.*

Comment: I'm afraid this is not what I asked for. I am looking for a way to search for file names with a pattern and open them in new split windows.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. Do you want to do it with Command-T? With another plugin? With built-in Vim features?

**With Command-T**

A quick look at [its documentation](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T/blob/master/doc/command-t.txt) suggests that Command-T doesn't do that. Did you check the plugin's issue tracker? Maybe someone has submitted a patch or a feature request?

**With another plugin**

[CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) is similar in spirit to Command-T but slightly different in design. It has the ability to open several files at once.

**With built-in features**

Vim can't do fuzzy matching but it is pretty powerful nonetheless. You can do:

```
:args file1 file2 file3 | argdo split
```

and benefit from * and ** as well as tab completion.

Drew Neil did a series on the arglist a few months ago. You can start with [this one](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/).

Comment: @romaini commandT does not provide that functionality indeed. I will try CtrlP and let you know, currently the way I do it is from terminal vi -o $(find * -name 'my_pattern'). by the way is there a better way to do it, even from the terminal?

Comment: Also, I have edited my question. I hope this is more clear now